# Initialize jssor slider after angular2 data binding complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, jssor

I'm trying to initialize jssor slider in my angular2 app. Slider images and videos are loaded from server. But slider inits before slider container.

**slider.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'slider',
    directives:[VideoComponent],
    providers:[SliderService],
    templateUrl: 'slider.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

    bannerData:any;
    jssorSlider:any;
ngOnInit() {
        this.banners();
    }
    banners(){
        this._sliderService.getBanners()
            .subscribe((result)=>{
                this.bannerData = result;
                if(this.bannerData){
                    this.setUpSlider();
                }
            })
    }

    setUpSlider(){
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", this.options);
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth) {
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth - 30);
                }
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
 }
}
```

**slider.component.html**

```
<div class="container slider-container" >


        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1140px; height: 442px;
        overflow: hidden;">
            <div  *ngFor="let item of bannerData">
                <img *ngIf="item.video_id == 0" u="image" src='{{item.image}}' />
                <single-video *ngIf="item.video_id>0" u="image" [initialData]="item"> In single video </single-video>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Is there any way to call the setUpSlider() after html loading complete? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call your function inside ngAfterViewInit
( it is called
After Angular creates the component's view(s).
).      https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: I tried it. But it isn't working :(

Comment: Hi @Shuvo I am trying the same. Did you find any solution ?